# Entity Framework and ObservableCollections

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, entity-framework, mvvm

I'm exploring Entity Framework using WPF/MVVM and this is probably as basic as it gets but I can't get it to work. I have an edmx diagram that contains two entities, OUTAGE_DETAILS and OUTAGE_TYPE_LOOKUP. I simply want to linq against one of the entities and return an ObservableCollection which I can bind to a DataGrid. Eventually I will add/modify records from the DataGrid. What am I doing wrong and is this the best approach to take for the eventual outcome of editing and adding records?

This is what I have:

```
private Data_Entities oeContenxt = new Data_Entities();

private ObservableCollection<OUTAGE_DETAILS> _outagecollection;
public ObservableCollection<OUTAGE_DETAILS> OutageCollection
{
   get { return _outagecollection; }
   set
   {
        if (value == _outagecollection) return;
        _outagecollection = value;
   }
}

private void ShowOutages()
{
   var query = (from o in oeContenxt.OUTAGE_DETAILS
                select o.OUTAGE_SEQ_ID).ToList();

   OutageCollection = new ObservableCollection<OUTAGE_DETAILS>(query.ToList()); // <- Error Here
}

// constructor
public MainWindowViewModel()
{
   this.ShowOutages();
}
```

and the error is:
`The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<WpfApplication1.OUTAGE_DETAILS>.ObservableCollection(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<WpfApplication1.OUTAGE_DETAILS>)' has some invalid arguments`

I believe this is a common error for this scenario but I haven't found a solution to it. Also, am I using the entity name OUTAGE_DETAILS correctly in the declaration of my collections?

Comment: Can you provide the code line that reports this error? This code snippet looks valid, so we need more details.

Comment: Thanks @CryptoGuy, I included the rest of my code.

Comment: (from o in oeContenxt.OUTAGE_DETAILS select o.OUTAGE_SEQ_ID).ToList() returns a list of the Ids, not the OUTAGE_DETAILS. Try just selecting "o".

Comment: Thanks @jhenninger24 that worked to return all fields and all records. What if I want to select only certain fields? If I want to update/add records do I just add them to the collection then save?

Answer (score 0):

for getting data with EF,

```
    public ObservableCollection<OUTAGE_DETAILS> LoadOutageDetails()
    {
        // Charge les données (Load data)
        oeContenxt.OUTAGE_DETAILS.Load();
        return oeContenxt.OUTAGE_DETAILS.Local;
    }
```

Use it in code behind of your view:

```
dtgrid.ItemsSource = LoadOutageDetails();
```

Or with MVVM, bind your vm on the dataContext of your View

```
this.DataContext = new MyViewModel();
```

In the XAML of your View :

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding AllOutageDetails}"></DataGrid>
```

And your VM :

```
class MyViewModel{
   private ObservableCollection<OUTAGE_DETAILS> _allOutageDetails;

        /// <summary>
        /// ObservableCollection de tous les outage details
        /// </summary>
        public ObservableCollection<OUTAGE_DETAILS> AllOutageDetails
        {
            get
            {
                return _allOutageDetails;
            }
            set
            {
                _allOutageDetails= value;
            }
        }

        public MyViewModel()
        {
            _allOutageDetails = LoadOutageDetails();
        }
}
```

Enjoy yourself!